# Get current time in C, function

Tags: c, time

I want to get current time (without a current date) in C. The main problem is when I want to do it with functions. When I dont use them, evertyhing is just fine. Can anybody tell me, why my code shows only an hour? (take a look at the attached image). Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

char* get_time_string()
{
    struct tm *tm;
    time_t t;
    char *str_time = (char *) malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    t = time(NULL);
    tm = localtime(&t);
    strftime(str_time, sizeof(str_time), "%H:%M:%S", tm);
    return str_time;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *t = get_time_string();
    printf("%s\n", t);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hint: check what `sizeof(str_time)` returns.

Comment: don't forget to `free` your string when you're done with it...

Comment: On a different note, 1) `sizeof(char) == 1` by definition and you should remove the multiplication, 2) you are not checking whether the allocation succeeded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `sizeof` operator returns the length of the variable `str_time` which is a pointer to char. It doesn't returns the length of your dynamic array.

Replace `sizeof(str_time)` by `100` and it will go fine.

Comment: `sizeof` is not a function. It's an operator.

Answer (score 7):

`sizeof(str_time)` gives you the size of `char*`.  You want the size of the buffer `str_time` points to instead.  Try

```
strftime(str_time, 100, "%H:%M:%S", tm);
//                 ^ size of buffer allocated for str_time
```

Other minor points - you should include `<stdlib.h>` to pick up a definition of `malloc` and should `free(t)` after printing its content in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
int main ()
 {
  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;

  time ( &rawtime );
  timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );
  printf ( "Current local time and date: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question, which is "why is my code not working?".

Answer (score 0):

Use This Concept Getting System Time and Updating it. I have used this in my project many years before. you can change it as per your requirements.

```
updtime()                 /* FUNCTION FOR UPDATION OF TIME */
{
 struct time tt;
 char str[3];
 gettime(&tt);
 itoa(tt.ti_hour,str,10);
 setfillstyle(1,7);
 bar(getmaxx()-70,getmaxy()-18,getmaxx()-30,getmaxy()-10);
 setcolor(0);
 outtextxy(getmaxx()-70,getmaxy()-18,str);
 outtextxy(getmaxx()-55,getmaxy()-18,":");
 itoa(tt.ti_min,str,10);
 outtextxy(getmaxx()-45,getmaxy()-18,str);
return(0);
}
The previous function will update time whenever you will call it like 

and this will give you time

 int temp;
 struct time tt;
 gettime(&tt);                       /*Get current time*/
 temp = tt.ti_min;
```

If you want to update time the you can use the following code.

```
   gettime(&tt);
   if(tt.ti_min != temp)  /*Check for any time update */
   {
    temp = tt.ti_min;
    updtime();
   }
```

This is complex code but if you understand it then it will solve your all problems.

Enjoy :)

Comment: This is not an answer to OP's question, which is "why is my code not working?". Issues with your code snippet: `updtime()` is no longer valid (implicit `int` was removed in C99), "UPDATION" is not a word, none of the functions you're using are standard C (or even POSIX), nor is `struct time`.

Answer (score 0):

In getting the time, you can try this one:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  printf("Time: %s\n", __TIME__);
  return 0;
}
```

Result:

**Time: 10:49:49**

Comment: `__TIME__` is a preprocessor macro that gives you the time when the program was *compiled*, not the current time when it runs.